# How does one access the configuration from inside a IPython 3.x / Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In particular I would like to know the `base_url` of the Notebook Server that the code is running in.

In IPython Notebooks version 2.x I used to do the following:

```python
config = get_ipython().config
print config['NotebookApp']['base_url']
```

However this no longer works in IPython Notebook 3.x / Jupyter Notebooks.

EDIT: Some more detail on what I am trying to achieve.

I run various IPython Servers in separate Docker containers on the same host which are accessed through different `base_url`s. I would like to use the [quantopian/qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) package to display Pandas DataFrames inside the Notebook. Initially `qgrid` did not handle custom `base_url` prefixes for serving up a local copy of the Javascript dependencies but the code above allowed me to find the `base_url` in IPython 2 and to inject the relevant `base_url` into the Javascript template.

I would also like to use the [mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/) library in the Notebook and when browsing their documentation I found that they also mention that in ["IPython 2.0+, local=True may fail if a url prefix is added (e.g. by setting NotebookApp.base_url)"](https://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.enable_notebook) so it seems that this is not an isolated problem and a good solution would be worthwhile.

Given @matt's comment below and thinking more about kernel vs frontend split, it makes sense that the NotebookApp config isn't accessible from the kernel. It's really the JS code that's generated that needs to know what the `base_url` is, so if someone can point me to where I can access this in the Notebook JS API, that should solve it.

Comment: Why do you want the `base_url`. What are you trying to achieve, then we can discuss where to get it. It depends on wether you do a JS extension, a server extension, or a kernel extension.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your comment. I've added more detail to the question. It's really in the JS extension that this is required. I hadn't thought about it very carefully and was trying to solve it in Python in the kernel since that's what I am more familiar with.

Comment: Added answer, haven't really looked at how mpld3 and qgrid do things, but I hope that will help. Feedback if things are missing is welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

From the frontend side, if you publish javasscript, and assuming you are in a notebook (keep in mind that being in JS does not necessary mean notebook, you could be  Atom-Hydrogen, or Jupyter-Sidecar) you can use a snipet like:

```
require(['base/js/utils'], function(utils){
    var base_url = utils.get_body_data('base-url')
})
```

The `data-base-url` attribute is set on the `<body>` tag of the notebook.

It is though not guarantied to stay this way. Usually, extension should be installed in the `nbextensions` folder, which should automatically resolve correctly:

```
require.config({

      ...
      paths: {
        nbextensions : '<base url>/nbextensions',
        kernelspecs : '<base url>/kernelspecs',
...
})
```

Nbextension is a search path, so if set correctly on the server, you shouldn't (most of the time) have to serve things yourself at custom URLs, nor to handle `base_url` yourself on frontend side.

Answer (score -1):

After quite a lot of digging into IPython internals I found something that works for me:

```python
from IPython.config.loader import load_pyconfig_files
config = get_ipython().config
profiledir = config['ProfileDir']['location']
nbconfig = load_pyconfig_files(['ipython_notebook_config.py'], profiledir)
print nbconfig['NotebookApp']['base_url']
```

EDIT: This works on my installation but I understand now that the kernel is not really the right place to get this info. I'll probably delete this answer once some better answers are up.

Comment: Be prepared for this to break in version 4. By design, the kernel, where your code is running, does not know about the notebook server.